# Extending String for Typesafety - Java

Tags: java, hibernate, oop, type-safety

I am considering a design in Java where I want a string object but with more 'type-safety' than just being of class `String`.  This because I have a number of 'POJO' objects for Hibernate, representing my database tables.  Each of these classes has a large number of public static fields representing the properties of the class, I.e.:

```
public class PersistantBean {
    public static String PROP_FIELD_COLUMN_ONE="columnOne";
    public static String PROP_FIELD_COLUMN_TWO="columnTwo";
    // [...]
```

These properties are used when we need to access a property in a generic way, e.g. for code I am currently writing `.parseAndSet(PROP_FIELD_PRICE,"£3.00")`.

I would like to be able to add a stronger type to the `PROP_FIELD_...` fields so that I could write

```
public class PersistantBean {
    public static PropertyName PROP_FIELD_COLUMN_ONE="columnOne";
    public static PropertyName PROP_FIELD_COLUMN_TWO="columnTwo";
    // [...]
```

with minimal changes to other parts of the project,

so that parseAndSet would look like:

```
public void parseAndSet(PropertyName prop, String priceToParse)
```

---

Essentially, I would like `PropertyName` to be a type that is like String in everyway apart from the compiler would error if I tried to put a `String` where a `PropertyName` was expected, is any design pattern like this possible.
(I am shying away from Enums, although now I mention it, Enums may be the way to go.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Java 1.5 and above, just use an [enum type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

For Java 1.4 and below, use the [typesafe enum pattern](http://www.javacamp.org/designPattern/enum.html). E.g.

```
public class Suit {
    private final String name;

    public static final Suit CLUBS =new Suit("clubs");
    public static final Suit DIAMONDS =new Suit("diamonds");
    public static final Suit HEARTS =new Suit("hearts");
    public static final Suit SPADES =new Suit("spades");    

    private Suit(String name){
        this.name =name;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return name;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why use this pattern instead of using an actual enum? This pattern was relevant with JDK 1.4, but it's not relevant anymore.

Comment: I'm going to echo the above comment, since as written, I do not see any advantage here over using an enum.

Comment: The overwhelming answer from everybody seems to be: 'Use Enums', I see now that trying to achieve a subclass of string (which Java doesn't allow) is more trouble than its worth, I have accepted your answer @donturner as you were the first to suggest Enums.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'd use an Enum.  That way you get compile-time checking.

If your Strings really have a good fairly standard naming convention, like "column" + "One", "Two", etc. as in your example, you could save a lot of work by combining an enum for the prefix with an int for the suffix.  So, create a class or utility method that takes an enum for the prefix, e.g. COLUMN, and combines it with an int, say 2, to yield "columnTwo".

An alternative might be be for your code, like parseAndSet, to validate the passed in String against an array or Collection of legal Strings, or maybe a regex, and throw an IllegalArgumentException.  You'd get runtime checking and if you have good unit tests this could work.

EDIT ADDED

@sethupathi.t had a nice idea in his answer - In some cases it may be preferable to make the 2nd argument (for which I used an int) also an enum.

Answer (score 2):

enum(enumeration) is a better idea, which above mentioned scenario.

eg:

enum PROP_FIELD_COLUMN {
   columnOne, columnTwo,etc
}

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, there are two reasonable ways to do what you want to do.

The first way (and probably best way, if it works for you) is to use an enum, as mentioned in another answer.

The second way, which may be necessary if you do not know all of your PropertyName's at runtime, would be to use a PropertyNameFactory along the lines of:

```
public class PropertyNameFactory
{

  public static PropertyName getPropertyName(String propertyName)
  {
    // Check validity of the propertyName against what ever rules we
    // have defined (maybe valid propertyNames are read from a DB at
    // startup, etc).
    if (isValid(propertyName))
    {
      // Ideally get from a cache, but for the sake of the example
      // we will create a new one...
      return new PropertyName(propertyName);
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid property name: " + propertyName);
  }

}
```

This is not ideal in that it does not provide true type safety of your property names, but it does ensure their validity.

Answer (score 1):

I have to second the Enum answers.

However, a more literal answer to your question is that Java provides an interface for String-like objects, [java.lang.CharSequence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html), and many parts of the standard Java libraries have been updated to accept CharSequence where appropriate.  This will not however give you the behavior that you want, which is to have your class behave as a subtype of String.